# Eclipse can't resolve a maven-bundle-plugin produced dependency

Tags: tycho

I made a bundle for a third-party lib with the maven-bundle-plugin as described here: http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp02/build01/pomfirst-thirdparty/pom.xml.

I can build my third-party lib and use it in another eclipse-plugin project which is build by the tycho-maven-plugin and whose dependencies are resolved by the target-platform-configuration plugin. So far so good.

But my eclipse can't resolve this dependency.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Errors messages?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are facing the problem explained in thread **[Eclipse support for pomDependencies=consider](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg00554.html)**.

The suggested solution is:

> You need to import pom-first projects into workspace, there is no
>   integration between PDE workspace target platform and Tycho
>   pomDependencies=consider feature.